# FOSS cross-platform data drive encryption

Tags: open-source, disk-encryption

Is there any dependable [FOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSS) that provides hard disk encryption such that a data drive (i.e. not a system drive) can be moved between Linux, OS X and Windows systems, and can be read from and written to on each of those platforms?

Answer (score 3):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

`Freeware & Source Available` disk encryption software for Windows 7/Vista/XP, Mac OS X and Linux. All OS ports `actively maintained` by the same developers.

If support for Mac OS X is not a criterion, then there is [LUKS](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) which is the `standard drive encryption` solution for Linux. The [FreeOTFE](http://freeotfe.org/index.html) project provides support for the LUKS format on Windows.

Comment: Note that for this to fit the OP's requirements, the true crypt volume must be formatted as a file system which all of the platforms support.

Comment: TrueCrypt is not FOSS.

Comment: @sampablokuper thanks... truecrypt is source-available and gratis... it is not an acknowledged libre software in the free-to-redistribute sense...

Comment: Exactly. Gratis, shmatis; I want FOSS :)

Comment: Progress on establishing FOSS credentials for TrueCrypt is potentially afoot: http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/

Answer (score 1):

The best suggestion I've yet received came from Daniel J. Luke (thanks, Daniel!), who pointed out that [EncFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS) might work. If/when I get around to testing it, I hope I'll remember to report back here :)